# Show multiple images from Strapi API in NextJS Frontend

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, strapi

I want to add a carousel to a dynamic [slug.js] page in NextJS. I am using Tailwind to style my pages and Strapi in my API. I am able to get one picture with           src={`http://localhost:1337${activity.titlePicture[0].formats.large.url}`}, but I do not know how I can get more than 1 picture. In the database titlePicture has multiple images. How can I get all the pictures of my API into the carousel?

[image: titlePicture collection from Strapi]

Comment: What have you tried, and what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use map function , as titlePicture is an array. Since map calls a function once for each element in an array. So I guess it goes as follows:

```
{activity.titlePicture.map((category) => (<img src={http://localhost:1337${category.formats.large.url})}
```

Here I have used category , you can use any other word instead of category. So map function will ensure and call each element.
I hope this answers your queries.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to configure the rewrites in your next app to forward all requests to the Strapi server.

To do this you need to update your **next.config.js** file and add the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  async rewrites() {
    return [{
      source: "/uploads/:slug",
      destination: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/uploads/:slug",
    }, ];
  },
  ...
}
```

Your NextJS app will redirect all requests that will start with /uploads/* to your Strapi server that will return the image from static assets folder, which is **strapiApp/public/uploads**

Then you can just use the data from your Strapi API like this:

```js
<Image
  src = {data.img.url}
  ...
/>
```